# How do I get terminals to not have the gap when I snap them to corners?

Tags: unity

[image: three terminals with slight gaps/borders]

See picture above to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: The gap looks like a border. I don't want to try to convince you that you really need an apple when you say you want an orange and add it as an answer but: have you considered switching to a tiling window manager? I recently migrated to i3, disabled all borders (I could do this selectively as well) and it's simple, bloat-free, customisable, etc. Screenshot - http://imgur.com/0FlPUmP http://i3wm.org

Comment: @MarcinKaminski try resizing two terminals like he has, it seems to "snap" to the shadow even if you resize them yourself.

Comment: With the "Terminitor" terminal you can do this by disabling "window gemotry hinting", https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150971 is this close to what you are looking for?

Comment: I think you just need to disable shadows, and possibly fix the theme you're using, if it has invisible borders (which it may have).

Comment: @dobey It happens with the default unity theme as well.

Comment: xterm doesn't have this problem just discovered this.

Comment: I kind of solved my problem by installing the terminator emulator.

Comment: @Mateo it was just a guess. I don't use Unity ;)